# How do i make a unittest ? what does it look like?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def abn_abc(voteslist):
    sums = {}
    for vote in votes:
        if vote in sums:
            sums[vote] += 1  
        else:
            sums[vote] = 1
    return tally_ballots(sums)
```

How do I write a unit test for this function?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
import unittest
from wherever import abn_abc

class AbnAbcTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_abn_abc(self):
        list_for_testing with = [<insert list here>]
        self.assertEqual(abn_abc(list_for_testing_with), <expected result>)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

[Here's the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.html).